# GIO library C: DBUS | GIOStream and GIOConnection

Tags: c, dbus, gio

Trying to compile following code in C (I'm not very good with it) and getting `Address boundary error`. It seems like a variable is uninitialized.

```
all:
  gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include test.c `pkg-config --cflags dbus-1` `pkg-config --libs dbus-1 gio-unix-2.0`
```

￼

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>

int main (){

    GIOStream stream;
    GDBusConnectionFlags flags = G_DBUS_CONNECTION_FLAGS_NONE;
    GError *gerr = NULL;

    GDBusConnection * gcon = g_dbus_connection_new_sync(&stream,
            NULL,
            flags,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &gerr);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the documentation for [GDBusConnection](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusConnection.html) and [GIOStream](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/GIOStream.html#g-io-stream-get-output-stream). 
I can't understand what is wrong with the code.  Can you explain?

Comment: After you make the call, what is contained in `gerr`? (that is the reason you have the `GError` pointer) -- check it. What is `stream` connected to? Is it an open GIOStream that has been validated as open and ready to receive/send information? Do you need calls to `g_io_stream_get_input_stream (GIOStream *stream);` or `g_io_stream_get_output_stream (GIOStream *stream);`? It appears you need to go back to both of the cookbooks cited and see if there are other parts of the recipe you missed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin After one more hour I figured out. The following works:

`GInputStream * ginput = g_memory_input_stream_new();
    GOutputStream * goutput = g_memory_output_stream_new (NULL, 0, realloc, free);
    GIOStream * stream = g_simple_io_stream_new(ginput, goutput);

    GDBusConnectionFlags flags = G_DBUS_CONNECTION_FLAGS_NONE;
    GError* gerr = NULL;

    GDBusConnection * gcon = g_dbus_connection_new_sync(stream,
            NULL,
            flags,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &gerr);
    if (gerr){
        printf(gerr->message, "%s");
    }`

Comment: Glad you have it working. I've not worked with DBUS, but have worked with GIO file monitoring a bit. Looks like connecting your ginput and goutput streams was the ticket -- even though a bit non-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

After few more time I figured out that following works:

```
GInputStream * ginput = g_memory_input_stream_new();
    GOutputStream * goutput = g_memory_output_stream_new (NULL, 0, realloc, free);
    GIOStream * stream = g_simple_io_stream_new(ginput, goutput);

    GDBusConnectionFlags flags = G_DBUS_CONNECTION_FLAGS_NONE;
    GError* gerr = NULL;

    GDBusConnection * gcon = g_dbus_connection_new_sync(stream,
            NULL,
            flags,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &gerr);
    if (gerr){
        printf(gerr->message, "%s");
    }
```